# Keyboard Appearance Defaults to UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault on Dismissal

Tags: iphone, keyboard, interface-builder, hide, appearance

First time Stack Overflow poster. Please bear with me! :)

I have a set of `UITextField`s whose keyboard appearance I set in Interface Builder. I'm using the `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` appearance (the translucent look) for my keyboards. However, whenever I call `resignFirstResponder` on any of these text fields to dismiss the keyboard, the keyboard's appearance defaults to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault` as it slides out of view. 1) Is there somewhere else that I need to set the appearance of the keyboard, 2) is this a bug with Interface Builder, or 3) am I just out of luck? While it isn't a huge deal, it is slightly jarring to suddenly see the keyboard change style as it's sliding down. Note that this behavior does not exist when the keyboard is sliding up into view as a result of my text field's becoming the First Responder, so it's a bit perplexing. Any insight?

Comment: This is happing for me on iOS7...grrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is curious, this issue seems to have been fixed in SDK 3.0. The rendering of the keyboard stays the same when being dismissed now.